# Soap Request Fails every X times

Tags: php, soap

I use soap to talk with FedEx.  However, in my logs, I get sometimes where it doesn't throw a error.  But craps out, and then sometimes I see the following below.  Any ideas?

SoapClient::__doRequest(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
known

UPDATE:

Turns out is was my resolvers that were bad on the server.  I changed them to.

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a network connectivity thing.

Your server cant connect to FedEx

Comment: It's weird how it's 1 order in 100.  The number starts to add up quickly though.  I wonder if it's them or us, or dns.  Trying to figure out where I should look to debug, if it's even possible to debug because it might be on fedex's side.  (+1 for your response)

Comment: in theory they could be throttling you?

Comment: You could always check the server is up and accessible before the SOAP request?>

Comment: I am going to call them now on the throttling.  Yes you are right.  Everything kind of points that direction.  If they aren't then soap might have a few limitations.